# Define CDN without editing MasterPage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I have found several articles referenced below about how to do this in SPOnline and I've see how to reference SPOnline CDN for OnPrem.  I want to make several public libraries available for all our internal sites, but I don't want to edit the master page for each site collection.  **What is the best practice?**

[Reference](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2015/08/using-a-cdn-for-static-resources-on-sharepoint-2016/);
[Reference](https://bob1german.com/2017/12/04/choosing-a-cdn-for-sharepoint-client-side-solutions/);
[Reference](http://julieturner.net/2016/09/code-creep-sharepoint-cdn/);
[Reference](https://chuvash.eu/2013/08/08/the-cdn-concept-in-sharepoint/);

Example:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://webAppUrl
$wa.WebService.SideBySideToken = $farm.BuildVersion.ToString()
$wa.WebService.CdnPrefix = "static.sharepointonline/bld"
$wa.WebService.EnableCdn = $true
$wa.WebService.Update()
```

Comment: Want to include the libraries of Font Awsome, MomentJS, and JQuerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint On-Premise, we can create a FARM feature and deploy all those scripts to Layout folder. then you can refer all the resource files in multiple site collections.

Check the articles below

[Packaging and Deploying SharePoint Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231544.aspx)

[Deploy Custom Css file in SharePoint with Solution Package](http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.sg/2010/05/deploy-custom-css-file-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that will create duplicate files on every site collection.  I would like to be able to reference multiple CDNs that are hosted by 3rd parties, ie, Google.

Comment: Deploy to Layout(C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\template\layouts) folder in server, not create duplicate files on every site collection.

Comment: I see, but to use them, I will need to use a custom master page to make use of them, correct?  Will the libraries in the layouts folder be available to a CWEP?

Comment: Yes, we can refer to the js/css files in Content Editor Web Part or Script Editor Web Part.